# MVC4 : User.IsInRole not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, simplemembership, asp.net-roles

I'm using the ASP.NET MVC SimpleMemberShip Provider,

There isn't any problem for a while after I logged in. I check if user is Boss, this is working.

```
if (User.IsInRole("Boss")) {
 //do something
}
```

But after a few minutes when I refresh the page ,`User.IsInRole("Boss")` always returns false.
I debugged and checked if user still logged in, yes, user is still there, nothing changed but IsInRole keeps returning false.

When I log out and log in again It starts working.

I think the problem is about `Sessions` but I couldn't find any solution.

This is what I have in `Web.config`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

### UPDATE:

I realized that happens when I rebuild my project.

Comment: `[Authorize]` applied? (just curious)

Comment: You're using `Sessions`? Could it be your that session expired?

Comment: @BradChristie, Yes the controller has `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: @WannaCSharp, No I'm not using session actually, I've never used session in my project. But membership provider must be using sessions, so I thought that problem would be about session. But if session expired why I can still get User.Identity.Name and Why authorization attribute not forcing me to log out?

Comment: Membership does not use Sessions.

Comment: @MystereMan, so as I understand the problem is sessions because membership does not use Sessions but role management does ?

Comment: No, Role management doesn't use sessions either.  It's all based on FormsAuthentication cookie, which is not related to session in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You could be losing your cookie.  Try adding:
     `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="2880" />`

this solved quite a few problems in our MVC app.